# Assistance with Node/link navigation in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am new to netlogo and developing a model that incorporates floor plans in which agents essentially evacuate the building avoiding obstacles etc. I have set up my model so that a node sprouts on every patch within the building, and by modifying an example i found on here by Luke C i have programmed the agents to select a path towards the exit.

The problem i am experiencing however, is that only one agent moves per tick. Is there any way i can change this? so for example, an agent will move forward 1 patch per tick, cycling through agents this way? I understand that more than one agent cannot move per tick. Thank's in advance!

Here is the code

```
extensions [ nw ]

breed [nodes node]
breed [evacuees evacuee]
breed [leaders leader]
breed [cells cell]


evacuees-own [panic calm speed fear direction enterthenetwork]
leaders-own [calm speed ]


to setup
ca
clear-all
set-default-shape turtles "person";
import-pcolors "foreal2.png"

set-default-shape nodes "circle"


ask patches with [ pcolor = white ] [

sprout-nodes 1 [
  set size 0.5
  set shape "circle"
  set color green
  ]
 ]

ask nodes [
create-links-with turtles-on neighbors4 [
  set color green
]
]

ask n-of evacnum nodes [
hatch 1 [
  set size 10
  set color green
  set breed evacuees
  set shape "person"
]
]

ask n-of 2 evacuees [
set color blue
]


ask patch 146 199
[

  sprout-cells 1 [
    set size 1.5
    set shape "box"
    set color yellow
  ]
 ]

  reset-ticks
  end

to avoid-walls
let front-patches patches in-cone 2 75
if [pcolor] of one-of front-patches = black [set heading heading - -120]
end



to go

let ready-evacuees evacuees with [ color = green ]


let evac-proxies turtle-set map [ i -> [nodes-on patch-here] of i ] sort 
ready-evacuees



ask one-of cells [


let node-proxy one-of nodes-on neighbors4


ask node-proxy [

  let my-evac-proxy min-one-of evac-proxies [length ( nw:turtles-on-path- 
to myself) ]

  ask my-evac-proxy [

    let path-to-follow nw:turtles-on-path-to myself


   ask turtle-set path-to-follow [
     set color orange
    ]

    let ready-evacuee one-of evacuees-here with [ color = green ]
    ask ready-evacuee[
      set color yellow
    ]

    ask ready-evacuee [
      foreach path-to-follow [
        n ->
        face n
        move-to n


        wait 0.1
      ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
  ]
 end
```

Comment: Hi Matt- you can definitely have multiple agents move each tick. You just have to `ask` the entire agentset that needs to move. From your code above, I'm not sure which agents those are- `cells` or `ready-evacuees` maybe? If that's the case, you could do `ask cells [ calculation... etc` and then each of the cells will choose their own node proxies and so on. However, you may need to provide a little more of your setup code to provide context as to which agents you actually want to move along the evacuation path.

Comment: Hi mate thank's for the quick response, i'm not 100% sure what you mean. I have updated the code to include everything. Whats happening at the moment is that agents are moving to the cell one by one and per tick. ideally i'm trying to have all agents moving towards exit at similar times, utilising their respective paths simultaneously, over a period of ticks. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete model that will give you a starting point. It includes movement toward an evacuation point and using `min-n-of` (like `min-one-of`) to find somewhere to move towards. You will need to use the speed slider (top middle) to slow this down to see the behaviour.

To build your model, try making smaller changes and getting them to work before adding the next element. For example, you should not consider walls until you have the movement sorted out. And it's unclear what all the different breeds are for.

```
breed [nodes node]

breed [evacuees evacuee]
evacuees-own
[ target
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-evacuees 100
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "person"
    set color blue
  ]
  create-nodes 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "circle"
    set color red
  ]
  ask evacuees
  [ set target one-of min-n-of 5 nodes [distance myself]
    face target
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  move
end

to move
  ask evacuees
  [ forward 0.25
    if distance target < 0.2
    [ set target one-of min-n-of 5 nodes [distance myself]
    ]
    face target
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has helped tremendously. I understand now that the go procedure functions the same way as the main function. So i should use this predominantly for calling other functions. i have incorporated this within my model and it's working well. Out of interest, the way i was dealing with obstacle avoidance was via the nw extension, essentially sprouting nodes on white patches and linking evacuees to these nodes. This way evacuees navigate a predetermined path similar to the a* algorithm avoiding obstacles. Is this something i can still incorporate?

Comment: Don't forget, we don't have your png file for colouring so white patches are meaningless. In principle though, yes, you can set up links between nodes and have the turtles follow those links. There is a model in the library that shows you how to do this - the Link Walking Turtles Example. My point was not so much about the walls, just that you tried to write the whole model without having anything working. NetLogo is hard to debug so it is critical to develop incrementally.

Comment: Understood. Thank's again for your help and apologies for my frustration.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not an easy fix of simply changing some of your code to make it work. You appear to have a fundamental conceptual issue. At a code level, you are using `wait 0.1` to stop everything happening immediately, and you don't have any command `tick` to advance time.

Conceptually, you need to separate the things that are there when you start and the things that happen through time. You have done this, breaking your model into the `setup` and `go` procedures as normal. But within the time progression, you need to imagine a `tick` as representing some specific amount of time (let's say 10 seconds). What happens within a 10s slice of time - all your evacuees move to the next node, or at least towards it or whatever.

As a first approximation:

1. replace your `ask one-of` type constructions with `ask` (that will instruct them all to do it).
2. remove the `wait` instruction
3. add `tick` as the last command in the go procedure (to advance the clock)

Then your go button will move through time every time you press it. You can edit the go button to repeatedly run the go procedure by checking the 'forever' box.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and suggestions, i will give this a go.

Comment: I've been provided with incredibly vague answers to my problem. Yes i can change the ask-one-of with an ask. However if i construct the function in this manner i get an error. The wait instruction is there simply to add a pause for visual effect as luke could confirm. What can i do here? I'm used to c++ and generally if theres a function called "min-one-of" there should be a function allowing me to use ALL? Or a way around at least. Can someone please provide me with some actually adaptable information.

Comment: The reason you have been given vague answers is because you are not asking an answerable question. You have misunderstood how to program in NetLogo at a conceptual level and probably need to redo the tutorials or look at the library models to understand agent-centric representation and the use of `ask` and `tick`. These two commands are fundamental to building a simulation and you aren't using them. For your visual effect, just slow down the simulation with the speed slider instead of adding pauses into your code.

Comment: Look up `ask` in the dictionary - it does exactly what you are trying to do, runs through all the evacuees (or other agentset) in a random order and has them execute the code that follows.